# How to run swtbot tests that use jmockit from ant?

Tags: ant, osgi, jmockit

we have a project created with Eclipse RCP and we are running GUI tests on it using SWTBot ( http://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot ).

Now we'd like to automate this test runs. Right now we have the ant task that runs all builds so we'd like ant to also run our GUI tests (according to http://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/Ant#Ant ).

Everything is fine, we created a ant task that starts OSGi framework with our exported product, starts JUnit headless execution, locates test plugin and test class and runs the test suite - but it fails.

The reason for it failing is that we are using jmockit within our tests. According to guide ( http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/gettingStarted.html ) we are able to run this test for running Eclipse (by adding jmockit to global classpath and adding -javaagent:jmockit.jar to VM arguments in test run configuration) but doing so in ant task (adding jvmarg and jmockit to classpath) failed.

With this configuration during test run we're getting following exception

```
mockit/MockUp
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mockit/MockUp
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mockit.MockUp
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:105)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

After that we osgi-fied jmockit and added it to our product, which resulted in following warning:

```
WARNING: JMockit was initialized on demand, which may cause certain tests to fail;
please check the documentation for better ways to get it initialized.
```

Doing a little digging I found following mail exchange: http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/issues/detail?id=203 and the last comment by rliesenf...@gmail.com saying:

> Given the exceptional difficulty (for me, at least) in making real progress on this, and the little motivation I have to work on it ("Eclipse JUnit Plugin tests" is a small "niche" environment, after all), I am closing this for now. Also, there is *a lot* of work to do in other areas of the toolkit (even without considering JMockit 2), so it's hard to justify time spent on stuff of this sort.

I was hoping that since that time this problem was solved or at least some workarround has been found.

Anyone ever encountered similar problem and would like to share their solution/suggestion?